# rsync with folder and file name pattern matching to copy files

Tags: macos, rsync

Right now I'm successfully running:

```
rsync -uvma  --include="*/" --include="*.css" --exclude="*" $spec_dir $css_spec_dir
```

In a shell script which copies all of the files in the source directory, that are `.css` files, into a target directory.

I want to do the same for HTML files, but only where they are in a subfolder with the name `template`.

Suppose I'm in directory `~/foo`, and I want to rsync where the `--include="*/"` only matches on subfolders with the name `template`.

- `~/foo/bar/template/baz/somefile.html` would match
- `~foo/bar/baz/qux/template/someotherfile.html` would match too
- `~/foo/bar/thirdfile.html` would NOT match

So I looked at [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4607603/rsync-filtering), but they don't quite match what I'm trying to do. The problem is, the list of folders I want to exclude is more than 1 folder--it's, say, 30 folders.

Comment: Please *always* include your OS. Solutions very often depend on the Operating System being used. Are you using Windows, Linux, Unix, OSX, BSD? Which version?

Comment: Doh! This is OS X Mavericks, BASH-based CLI.